# ERROR from UglifyJs Unexpected character '@'

Tags: angular, typescript, uglifyjs

I am getting below error when my Angular 6 App build as `ng build ---prod`

> ERROR in scripts.28e0dfadf7f39e74e940.js from UglifyJs Unexpected
>   character '@' [scripts.28e0dfadf7f39e74e940.js:13,0]

What could be the issue?

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: do you have any external script defined in your angular.json ?

Comment: @YoukouleleY Yeah. `node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.min.js` and a ts file with custom functions for `Pipe, PipeTransform`

Comment: as already answered, you can't import typescript files in there

Answer (score 1):

UglifyJS does not support ES2015 or higher. Decorators are not yet part of any ES specification, hence they are not supported. You have to transpile them firstly.